# Evaluating a string in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I wrote a code in kotlin for evaluating a given string from Divison to subtraction, it works but it gives the wrong answer, for example i got a string x in the first line which have answer -215.96666 whereas the answer from code is -237.366666 idk where the error is. i saw more people using stack for doing it, but i wanted to do this way for evaluating a string

```
var x : String = "5+4-10x20-40/30x20+34/20"

fun div(x: String): String {
    val lis1 = x.split("-").toMutableList()
    for (ele1 in lis1) {
        if ("/" in ele1) {
            val pos1 = lis1.indexOf(ele1)
            val lis2 = ele1.split("+").toMutableList()
            for (ele2 in lis2) {
                if ("/" in ele2) {
                    val pos3 = lis2.indexOf(ele2)
                    val lis3 = ele2.split("x").toMutableList()
                    for (ele3 in lis3) {
                        if ("/" in ele3) {
                            val pos4 = lis3.indexOf(ele3)
                            val lis4 = ele3.split("/")
                            val div = (lis4[0].toDouble() / lis4[1].toDouble()).toString()
                            lis3[pos4] = div
                        }
                    }
                    lis2[pos3] = lis3.joinToString("x")
                }
            }
            lis1[pos1] = lis2.joinToString("+")

        }
    }
    return (lis1.joinToString("-"))
}

fun mul(x : String) : String{
    val lis1 = x.split("-").toMutableList()
    for (ele1 in lis1) {
        if("x" in ele1){
            val pos1 = lis1.indexOf(ele1)
            val lis2 = ele1.split("+").toMutableList()
            for(ele2 in lis2){
                if("x" in ele2){
                    val pos2 = lis2.indexOf(ele2)
                    val lis3 = ele2.split("x")
                    val mul = (lis3[0].toDouble() * lis3[1].toDouble()).toString()
                    lis2[pos2] = mul
                }
            }
            lis1[pos1] = lis2.joinToString("+")
        }
    }
    return (lis1.joinToString("-"))
}

fun add(x : String): String {
    val lis1 = x.split("-").toMutableList()
    for(ele1 in lis1){
        if("+" in ele1){
            val pos1 = lis1.indexOf(ele1)
            val lis2 = ele1.split("+")
            val add = (lis2[0].toDouble() + lis2[1].toDouble()).toString()
            lis1[pos1] = add
        }
    }
    return (lis1.joinToString("-"))
}

fun sub(x : String) : String{
    val lis1 = x.split("-").toMutableList()
    var sub = 0.0
    for(ele1 in lis1){
        sub -= ele1.toDouble()
    }
    return (sub.toString())
}

fun eval(x: String): String {
    val divanswer = div(x)
    val mulanswer = mul(divanswer)
    val addanswer = add(mulanswer)
    return sub(addanswer)
}

fun main(args: Array<String>){
    println(eval(x))
}




i wanted the answer as -215.96666 but the answer given by code is -237.366666
```

Comment: I don't think that this should be done this way. You should look into writing a parser for evaluating arithmetic expressions.

Comment: @lukas.j Full parser is the correct way, but I really appreciate creativity of the OP. They look for a way how to do this by their own, they will learn much more with this attitude than authors of typical questions: "How to write calculator, please help.". Also, I think this approach should ultimately work, however, it would be pretty hard to add support for parenthesis.

Comment: @broot I agree with you about the creativity and the learning process. But on the other hand, evaluating arithmetic expressions has been solved decades ago and is perhaps the wrong place to invest time. Probably the two most important solutions are, first, what I would call „expression-term-factor recursion" and, second, converting the input string into a stack of operators and operands and then infix to postfix and evaluating the stack. It might make more sense to spend time developing custom code based on these known solutions. But I do understand what you mean in regard of this question.

Comment: @lukas.j yes, it's like a wrong place to invest time, but i really get a liking for coding when i do these kinda problems, So for me its not like wasting time but just making me involed in stuffs i liked, i asked my friends and in many websites, the answer was simply use stack or array to do it, but if there's another way to make it but it's a mess i will surely try it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of this specific input, there are two bugs involved.

First bug is related to the fact you first process `+` and then `-`, but in mathematics we should process them together, from left to right. As a result, your algorithm processes this: `1-1+1` (correct answer: `1`) as: `1-(1+1)` (answer: `-1`). Alternatively, I believe handling `-` first and then `+` should work properly.

Second bug is that in `sub()` you start from `0` and subtract even the first number, but the first number should be actually added or used as an initial value.

I believe after fixing these two bugs, it should provide a correct answer for this specific input, but there are probably more bugs like these. For example, you incorrectly handle chains of the same operator, you only care about the first pair, so `1+1+1` becomes `2` (and then it is turned to `-2` due to earlier mentioned bug).

As a general advice, learn to use a debugger and analyze how your data changes while your code is processing it. Even if you simply print your intermediate results: `divanswer`, `mulanswer` and `addanswer` and then run them through Google for processing, you will notice there is a problem somewhere at the `add()` step. Then rinse and repeat until everything works correctly.

Comment: thanks it was the subtraction and addition part which caused the trouble, now i changed and merged it into one, now i get the correct answer for the strings i used, now its just the paranthesis part i need to complete, again thanks for that.!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @broot for spotting this, the problem was with the addition and subtraction part, now that i merged them into one and got the correct answers for strings i input, here is the full code corrected.

```
var x : String = "5+4-10x20-40/30x20+34/20"

fun div(x: String): String {
    val lis1 = x.split("-").toMutableList()
    for (ele1 in lis1) {
        if ("/" in ele1) {
            val pos1 = lis1.indexOf(ele1)
            val lis2 = ele1.split("+").toMutableList()
            for (ele2 in lis2) {
                if ("/" in ele2) {
                    val pos3 = lis2.indexOf(ele2)
                    val lis3 = ele2.split("x").toMutableList()
                    for (ele3 in lis3) {
                        if ("/" in ele3) {
                            val pos4 = lis3.indexOf(ele3)
                            val lis4 = ele3.split("/")
                            val div = (lis4[0].toDouble() / lis4[1].toDouble()).toString()
                            lis3[pos4] = div
                        }
                    }
                    lis2[pos3] = lis3.joinToString("x")
                }
            }
            lis1[pos1] = lis2.joinToString("+")

        }
    }
    return (lis1.joinToString("-"))
}

fun mul(x : String) : String{
    val lis1 = x.split("-").toMutableList()
    for (ele1 in lis1) {
        if("x" in ele1){
            val pos1 = lis1.indexOf(ele1)
            val lis2 = ele1.split("+").toMutableList()
            for(ele2 in lis2){
                if("x" in ele2){
                    val pos2 = lis2.indexOf(ele2)
                    val lis3 = ele2.split("x")
                    val mul = (lis3[0].toDouble() * lis3[1].toDouble()).toString()
                    lis2[pos2] = mul
                }
            }
            lis1[pos1] = lis2.joinToString("+")
        }
    }
    return (lis1.joinToString("-"))
}

fun final(x: String): Double {
    val substr = StringBuffer()
    var answer = 0.0
    var opr = '+'
    for(ele in x.indices){
        var current = x[ele]
        if(current in '0'..'9' || current == '.'){
            substr.append(current)
        }
        if(current == '-' || current == '+'){
            var operand = substr.toString().toDouble()
            substr.setLength(0)
            when (opr){
                '+' -> answer += operand
                '-' -> answer -= operand
            }
            opr = current
        }
    }
    val num = substr.toString().toDouble()
    when(opr){
        '+' -> answer += num
        '-' -> answer -= num
    }
    return answer
}


fun eval(x: String): Double {
    val divanswer = div(x)
    return final(mul(divanswer))
}

fun main(args: Array<String>){
    println(eval(x))
}
```